# How can I access resource files from within a Java .app bundle running on OS X, Java 7?

Tags: java, macos, java-7, resource-files, app-bundle

Note that I am talking about Java 7, since the info.plist specification for a Java .app bundle seems to have changed a bit since Java 6.

Currently my code looks like this:

```
  File file = new File( "documentation/index.html" );
  if (file.exists()) {
      // opens the URI in the browser
      GUIUtils.openURI( file.toURI() );
  } else {
      // opens the URI in the browser
      GUIUtils.openURI( getClass().getResource( "/documentation/index.html" ).toURI() );
  }
```

In the `Java` subfolder in the app bundle, I have a "documentation" subfolder. I have tried multiple things, to no avail:

- In the info.plist, setting the working directory to the Java folder (with a `-Duser.dir` JVMArgument property) - the file seemingly has the right path, but `file.exists()` returns false.
- Trying to set the ClassPath to the Java folder. (`getClass().getResource()` still returns null)

Comment: I guess I'd extract the file to a temp folder and open it from there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're prepared to use the `com.apple` extensions, `com.apple.eio.FileManager.getPathToApplicationBundle()` will give you the base path to your bundle, and you can then create a `File` relative to that.

Comment: Though we're cross-platform, we can call that method via reflection, so it works. Thanks!

Comment: In my case, I needed to get the path to a file within the Resources folder of the application bundle. `com.apple.eio.FileManager.getResource("filename.txt")` is what I was looking for, but your answer led me to that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As of Java 9, `com.apple` is not accessible.

Java 9 uses modules to export (and expose) packages so `com.apple` is now unusable and deprecated. According to [this](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/272), `java.awt` should provide similar API functionalities.

Just wanted to provide this update as I ran into this issue following the accepted answer.

`System.getenv("LOCALAPPDATA")` can be used as an option to get application environment.